# SQLAlchemy - Why I keep receiving the object model instead of the value of query, after .query().all()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is my code

```
Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine("postgresql://r****:Z*******@1******:*43*/r**i*g")

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


class StandardRouting(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'standard_routing'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    platform_name = Column(String(255))
    delivery_type = Column(String(255))
    transport_rule = Column(String(255))
    shipping_type = Column(String(255))
    fm = Column(String(255))
    fm_carrier = Column(String(255))
    lh = Column(String(255))
    lh_carrier = Column(String(255))
    lm = Column(String(255))
    lm_carrier = Column(String(255))
    __table_args__ = (
        {'schema': 'routing'},
    )

data = Session.query(StandardRouting).all()
```

When I print out `data` i got this

```
[<__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A872C40>, <__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A872CA0>, <__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A872F10>, <__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A872F70>, <__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A872FD0>, <__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A872E80>, <__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A872DC0>, <__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A872100>, <__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A8A0040>, <__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A8A00D0>, <__main__.StandardRouting object at 0x0000025B0A8A0160>]
```

I really dont know why I can not access to the data and keep receiving the object.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is the Python SQL toolkit and **Object Relational Mapper**(**ORM**) that gives application developers the full power and flexibility of SQL. You will have a object and from that object you can access data I guess. Maybe you can do the below to fetch data

```
for record in data:
   print(record.id, record.platform_name)
```

It is giving you the object of the record and you can access column data using member variables of that object.

Hope I understood your question.

Comment: For the record: SQLAlchemy is not *just* an ORM. There's more to it than that.

Comment: let me edit it.